# query to search in an object using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a search box that takes the input and get the matched data from the data base.I am using mongoose for query.
Below is the query

```
exports.search = function(req, res) {
    QuestionList.find({
            $elemMatch: {
                quesListName:req.body
            }
        },
        function(err, questionList) {
            if (err) {
                return handleError(res, err);
            }
            return res.status(200).json(fnData(questionList));
        });
};
```

i don't understand where i am going wrong because every time when i make ajax call i am getting empty array.

Comment: quesListName stores string type Value ?

Comment: This Statement is Wrong:
  
quesListName:req.body

It must be  quesListName:req.body['textboxname']